# Python Selenium error Element is not reachable by keyboard

Tags: python, selenium, keyboard

I've been learning Selenium for about a week and in this project I'm trying to make a bot on Twitter that automatically tweet something. Everything worked out from the login page but when I got into the 'new tweet' tab I got this error saying the element is not reachable by keyboard:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <div class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

This is the XPATH:

```
//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div
```

The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\geckodriver-v0.29.0-win64\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('https://twitter.com/login')
sleep(3)
box_login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/label/div/div[2]/div/input').send_keys('***')
box_password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/label/div/div[2]/div/input').send_keys('***')
box_submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[3]/div/div/span/span')
box_submit.click()
sleep(5)
# Works until here, where it clicks the new tweet box.

tweet = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr", " " ))]')
tweet.click()
tweet.send_keys('Hello, world. This is my first tweet.')
tweet_submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "r-1fneopy", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "r-jwli3a", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "r-qvutc0", " " ))]')
tweet_submit.click()
```

As I said in the commentary it worked until the click on tweet box but got the error when trying to type something on it. Been searching for a solution for about 2 days now, hope someone can help me out!

Comment: you need to target <input> tag.  (This may show up after focus is set, or click...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the class I was looking for is `class="notranslate public-DraftEditor-content"` and now it works fine!